# submit input position fixed right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the form. I want my .form-main__submit to always stick to the right side of the form no matter what. If I use position absolute on submit button and add top: ..px and left ..px it won't be web-responsive. What is the best way to make the input button fixed to the right side of the form?

My css code so far:

```
.form-main {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    position: relative;
    border-color: lightgray;
    min-width: 60%;
}


.form-main__submit {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}



<div class="container">
      <div class="header">Sign in</div>
      <form class="form-main" action="#" method="post">
        <div>

          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input class="form-main__input" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1">
        </div>  
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input class="form-main__input" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2">
        </div> 
        <div>
          <input class="form-main__submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `right: 0` on `.form-main__submit` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `float` property and set it's value to `right`.

```
.form-main__submit {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you use `bootstrap`

```css
.form-main {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    position: relative;
    border-color: lightgray;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}


.form-main__submit {
    float:right;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<div class="container">
      <div class="header">Sign in</div>
      <form class="form-main col-md-6 col-sm-6" action="#" method="post">
        <div>

          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input class="form-main__input" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1">
        </div>  
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input class="form-main__input" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2">
        </div> 
        <div>
          <input class="form-main__submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```